# IOS 13 APNS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios13

1. In capabilities, both Push Notification and Background Mode (Remote notification) is opened.
2. I check the value of `UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` in my homepage. The value is true
3. I use 4G/3G not wifi (will it influence the APNS call back?)
4. I use Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) and the device is Iphone 11
5. Both `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` not called
6. my code:

   ```
    fileprivate func registerPushService() {
      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      center.delegate = self
      center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert]) { (granted, error) in
        if (granted) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
   ```

`registerPushService()` is called on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

=============

Looks like if allowed wifi environment only ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps the *.provisional* option set ?

```
requestAuthorization(options: [.provisional, .badge, .sound, .alert])
```

I had the behaviour you describe with this option. When I removed it, the registration went ahead and I got the token. I still haven't figured out how to force it to get a token with this option short of sending  local notification first to prompt the user for acceptance of notifications.

Answer (score -1):

I would actually move `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` outside of the `requestAuthorization` block. The confusing thing about this API is that calling `registerForRemoteNotifications()` and receiving a device token does not require user permission - requesting the different notification types (badge, sound, alert) is what actually triggers it. Also be sure to try this on a real device - not simulator. If I recall correctly, remote notifications do not work in simulator and the delegate callbacks will not be called.

Comment: I ensure registerForRemoteNotifications is called. because UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications is true. And I also tried move registerForRemoteNotifications outside. It is not worked for me

Comment: Note: these callbacks will be made only if the application has successfully registered for user notifications with registerUserNotificationSettings:, or if it is enabled for Background App Refresh.